# Chai: expecting an error or not depending on a parameter

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I've been trying to do a text of a function that handles errors in a way that, if it is a valid error, it is thrown, but if it is not, then nothing is thrown. The problem is that i cant seem to set the parameter while using:

```
expect(handleError).to.throw(Error);
```

The ideal would be to use:

```
expect(handleError(validError)).to.throw(Error);
```

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

code of the function:

```
function handleError (err) {
    if (err !== true) {
        switch (err) {
            case xxx:
            ...
        }
        throw "stop js execution";
    else {}
}
```

And the code of the test (not working as intended):

```
it("should stop Javascript execution if the parameter isnt \"true\"", function() {
    expect(handleError).to.be.a("function");
    expect(handleError(true)).to.not.throw(Error);
    expect(handleError("anything else")).to.throw(Error);
});
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling handleError, then passing the result to expect. If handleError throws, then expect never even gets called.

You need to defer calling handleError until expect is called, so that expect can see what happens when the function is called. Fortunately, this is what expect wants:

```
expect(function () { handleError(true); }).to.not.throw();
expect(function () { handleError("anything else") }).to.throw("stop js execution");
```

If you read the [documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) for throw, you'll see that the associated expect should be passed a function.

Comment: how this can be achieved with 'should'?

Comment: ok, I got it `should.Throw(function(){handleError("anything else");}, Error);`

Comment: Do not type 'handleError().should.throw()'. It just '(function(){handlerError();}).should.throw()'. I didn't know this... It throw much time to trash.

Comment: I went with `expect(() => throwAnError(true)).to.throw()`;

Comment: This makes more sense than the question that this was marked as a duplicate of

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same problem today and opted for another solution not mentioned here: partial function application using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions_(currying)):

```
expect(handleError.bind(null, true)).to.not.throw();
expect(handleError.bind(null, "anything else")).to.throw("stop js execution");
```

This has the benefit of being concise, using plain old JavaScript, requiring no extra functions and you can even provide the value of `this` should your function depend on it.

Comment: "requiring no extra functions" - that's not true. Under the hood "bind" method creates HOF (High Order Function). That said it's kinda same solution as mentioned above except ability to pass context more explicitly.

Comment: @Skay "no extra functions" just means you don't need to write a helper function [as this answer suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34590246/5892036). `bind()` itself creates and returns a new function, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the function call in a Lambda, as recommended by David Norman, is certainly one good way to solve this problem.

You might add this to your testing utilities, though, if you're looking for a more readable solution. This function wraps your function in an object with a method `withArgs`, which allows you to write the same statement in a more readable way. Ideally this would be built into Chai.

```
var calling = function(func) {
  return {
    withArgs: function(/* arg1, arg2, ... */) {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      return function() {
        func.apply(null, args);
      };
    }
  };
};
```

Then use it like:

```
expect(calling(handleError).withArgs(true)).to.not.throw();        
expect(calling(handleError).withArgs("anything else")).to.throw("stop js execution");
```

It reads like english!

Comment: What benefits brings your solution compared to built-in "bind" function?

Comment: @Skay readability. It accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I use ES2015 with babel stage-2 preset, and if you do so, you can use this as well.

I took @StephenM347 solution and modified it a little to be shorter an even more readable IMHO :

```
let expectCalling = func => ({ withArgs: (...args) => expect(() => func(...args)) });
```

Usage :

```
expectCalling(handleError).withArgs(true).to.not.throw();        
expectCalling(handleError).withArgs("anything else").to.throw("stop js execution");
```

*Note: if you wish the same usage (and stick to use `expect()` as is) :*

```
    let calling = func => ({ withArgs: (...args) => () => func(...args) });
```