# In chai.js, where is the code that actually invokes the function passed in to `expect()`?

Tags: javascript, testing, chai

I'm using [Chai.js](http://www.chaijs.com/) and [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised) to test some of my promise-returning library functions. I was stuck testing exceptions thrown from such a function because it turns out that the `expect()` function can also *invoke* a function rather than just examine the return value of a function and I was passing in the wrong thing.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21587239/562139

(1) Is this documented somewhere? I couldn't find anywhere in the Chai.js documentation/page where it indicates that the [expect API](http://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect) could take both values *and* functions that are executed before being tested/asserted upon.

(2) Where in the chai.js library source is the test for whether the argument to expect is a function, causing the function to be invoked before the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expect` function doesn't expect a function as argument. It's `throw` implementation that expect a [function to evaluate](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw)

The code is here for the [function](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/11612e97da85c7eafb573f69a71ecc640c32ef40/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L2614) and [assertion](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/11612e97da85c7eafb573f69a71ecc640c32ef40/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L2620)

Comment: No, you must pass a function as argument to `expect` but the expectation is done in the implementation of `throw` and not in the implementation of `expect`