# Chai expect .to.throw(Error) not working as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

My assertion is:

```
    it.only('should throw an error if the transcription cannot happen', () => {
        expect(TranscriptLib.myFunc({ data }, '1')).to.throw(Error)
    })
```

My function is:

```
myFunc: (data, id) => {

                throw new Error({
                    message: 'Transcription failed',
                    error: someError
                })
```

However, when I run my test, the log shows:

```
     Error: [object Object]
```

and the test fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC `expect().to.throw` expects a function, it doesn’t use function-rewriting magic to wrap an expression with a `try`.

Comment: @Ry- that did it. Please leave an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a duplicate of [Mocha / Chai expect.to.throw not catching thrown errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21587122)

The most straightforward way to fix your issue would be to make the call to your code from an arrow function:

```
it.only('should throw an error if the transcription cannot happen', () => {   
  expect(() => TranscriptLib.myFunc({ data }, '1')).to.throw(Error)
})
```

As the answers on the other question show you can also use `.bind` to create a new function, and so on and so forth.