# Mocha/Chai: testing thrown Errors with error message

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js, chai

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587122/mocha-chai-expect-to-throw-not-catching-thrown-errors):

I don't only want to test if the function throws an error but also if the thrown error has the same Error Message.
So i tried:

```
expect(Person.getPerson.bind(Person, id)).to.throw(new Error(`Person ${id} not found`));
```

inside the getPerson function an Error is thrown lilke this:

```
if (!isPersonExistent(id)) {
   throw new Error(`Person ${id} not found`);
}
```

and the given message looks like this:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function: bound getPerson] to throw 'Error: Person 1 not found' but 'Error: Person 1 not found' was thrown
```

I guess it has something to do with the two error objects being two different objects. But how do I also test if they have the same error message. Optimally all in one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that your assertion is failing because Chai `.throw` is comparing error objects by strict equality. From [the spec](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw):

> When one argument is provided, and it’s an error instance, `.throw` invokes the target function and asserts that an error is thrown that’s strictly (`===`) equal to that error instance.

The same spec explains:

> When two arguments are provided, and the first is an error instance or constructor, and the second is a string or regular expression, `.throw` invokes the function and asserts that an error is thrown that fulfills both conditions as described above.

where

> `.throw` invokes the target function and asserts that an error is thrown with a message that contains that string.

So the way to test the desired behavior is using two arguments like this:

```js
expect(Person.getPerson.bind(Person, id)).to.throw(Error, `Person ${id} not found`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
  Person.getPerson(id);
} catch (error) {
  expect(error.message).to.be('Error: Person 1 not found');
  return;
}
expect.fail('Should have thrown');
```

Comment: 'error' is of type 'unknown'. So this is not helpful.