# How to test for a specific error message in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

```js
import assert from 'assert';
const fn = () => { throw new Error('bar') }

describe('fn()', () => {
  it('should throw "foo"', () => {
    assert.throws(fn, Error, 'foo');
  });
});
```

It (incorrectly) says the test passed:

```
fn()
    √ should throw "foo"
    
  1 passing (8ms)
```

This is wrong because `fn()` throws `'bar'` not `'foo'`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are using chai as assertion framework? Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587122/mocha-chai-expect-to-throw-not-catching-thrown-errors

Comment: ``"foo"`` is an instance of ``String``, since you didn't do ``throw new Error("foo");``.

Comment: @n9iels I'm using Mocha.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes I updated my code to `throw new Error('foo')` and now all I get is `Error: foo`, instead of the test passing.

Comment: I made progress.  It passes the test if the function throws an error, and fails otherwise.  But it passes for ALL error messages.   I need it to pass only for a SPECIFIC error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install `chai` and use its `assert` and `expect`.

```js
import chai from 'chai';
const { assert, expect } = chai;
const fn = () => { throw 'foo' }

describe('fn()', () => {
  it('should throw "foo"', () => {
    expect(fn).to.throw('foo');
  });
});
```

Comment: Potential problem with this is: what happeneds if `fn()` does not throw anything? Better would be to store the error message in a variable and perform the assertion outside below the catch

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message), if you pass a constructor the library performs `instanceof` validation, if you want to check props then use a validation object or Regex e.g.

```
assert.throws(fn, {
  name: 'Error',
  message: 'foo'
});
```