# Mocha - Assert asynchronous function throws exception

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I am trying to test if an `async` function is going to throw an exception, but I keep getting this error:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
```

I am using Mocha with Chai's assertion library.

```
it('Throw an error', async () => {
    assert.throws(async () => {
        await retrieveException();
    }, Error);

    const retrieveException = async () => {
        // code snippit
        throw new Error('This is an error');
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with either checking for a thrown exception, the async nature, or both?

#### References

I have seen previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587122/mocha-chai-expect-to-throw-not-catching-thrown-errors) (where the one answer goes through the three different libraries [assert and the two BDD methods]), and I was unable to get something to work.

[This article](https://exceptionshub.com/mocha-chai-expect-to-throw-not-catching-thrown-errors-2.html) doesn't help much either.

Nor the [documentation article](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message) from Node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expect().to.throw(Error)` will only work for sync functions. If you want a similar feature using async functions take a look at [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised)

E.g.

```js
import chai, { assert } from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('63511399', () => {
  it('Throw an error', async () => {
    const retrieveException = async () => {
      throw new Error('This is an error');
    };
    return assert.isRejected(retrieveException(), Error);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  63511399
    ✓ Throw an error


  1 passing (29ms)
```

Comment: `chai-as-promised` requires `chai` >= 2.1.2 and < 5.

Answer (score -1):

In Node JS sins v10.0.0 there is:

```
assert.rejects(asyncFn[, error][, message])
```

that works to check exceptions in async functions,

with Mocha it will looks like this:

```
it('should tests some thing..', async function () {
  await assert.rejects(async () => {
    throw new Error('This is an error')
  }, 'Error: This is an error')
})
```