# Chai expect "not.to.throw" not catching unexpected error

Tags: chai

I'm testing a function using Chai's `expect ... not.to.throw` pattern (v4.3.4):

```js
describe('parseInt', () => {
  it('does not throw TypeError', () => {
    // foo is not defined, so a ReferenceError is thrown... somewhere?
    expect(() => parseInt(foo)).not.to.throw(TypeError);
  });
});
```

The closure throws an error, but I don't see this error anywhere in the output (running mocha). The test passes without the slightest indication of the problem inside the closure.

I expect to at least see the error in the console, even if the tests pass.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440336/54426) says that such errors must be run like so:

```js
// wrapping describe/it are elided
try {
  expect(() => parseInt(foo)).not.to.throw(TypeError);
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).to.be.a(ReferenceError); // should PASS, and does
}
```

This passes, but doesn't appear to be testing the second condition. I can flip it and the test still passes:

```js
// wrapping describe/it are elided
try {
  expect(() => parseInt(foo)).not.to.throw(TypeError);
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).not.to.be.a(ReferenceError); // should FAIL, but does not
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you debugged what the error is inside the catch?

Comment: @EduardoHernández I can't see logged output from a console.log placed in the catch block, suggesting it is never run.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

I think the behavior you are observing is actually expected. The original post you referenced may be misleading.

Consider the following test:

```js
// describe/it wrappers have been redacted
expect(()=>parseInt(foo)).to.not.throw(TypeError)
```

Should this test pass or fail? Intuitively it should pass since the assertion is met: a `TypeError` was not thrown.

Again for the following test, should `'hello there'` be logged to the console?

```js
// describe/it wrappers have been redacted
try {
  expect(() => parseInt(foo)).to.not.throw(TypeError);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('hello there')
}
```

- If yes, then the statement `expect(() => parseInt(foo)).to.not.throw(TypeError)`, must throw.
- And for it to throw, the assertion - not throw a `TypeError` - must not be met, but we have already established that the assertion *is* met, and so no exception is thrown.
- Therefore, all code in the `catch` block is unreachable.

This is why the second assertion in your original example is never executed. It will only be reached if the code somehow threw a `TypeError` and caused the assertion to fail.

#### Possible solution

For the approach you are taking, I think it could work if there was a way to tell `mocha`/`chai` to still go ahead and propagate the error that is thrown by the target function even if the assertion is met. I am unsure of if there is a way to do this, though.

#### Alternative approach

Alternatively, I think you can get the same (or similar) outcome for the test you have in mind by doing this instead:

```js
// describe/it wrappers have been redacted
const myFunc = () => parseInt(foo)
expect(myFunc).to.not.throw(TypeError)
expect(myFunc).to.throw(ReferenceError)
```

Here are the assumptions underlying the above test:

- You are expecting an error
- The error should under no circumstances be a `TypeError`
- The error thrown should always be a `ReferenceError`.

In case these assumptions do not match what you are currently testing for, or if my alternate approach does not satisfy your needs, kindly let me know!

PS, I used `mocha: "^9.1.0"` and `chai: "^4.3.4"` for these tests.

Comment: I wasn't being clear that these tests were run in the context of a Mocha/Chai setup, so there is wrapping context that wasn't shown. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Gotcha! I tested things out again within a mocha context and I think I see what the issue is. I will update my answer.